# How to add vertical line division and legend in curve box html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

[image]

I have this image and I want to divide this box in three sections and need a legend on the top just like how it is in image.

Following is the code I did till yet and having literally not idea about the vertical line ( with the space between the top and the bottom) and the legend on top with curve borders.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 650px;
  height: 150px;  
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="rcorners2"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

I am really new in HTML CSS! Please help me with the code ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 150px; 
    position: relative;
  } 
  .legend {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    width: 30%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    left: 35%;
  }
#rcorners2 {
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
  .line {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border-left: 2px solid green;
  }
  .line:first-child {
    border-left: none;
  }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="rcorners2">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="legend"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome :) but I strongly recommend you to learn some html-css theory: especially about positiining, display property and padding and margins. If you need any explanation about layout that I wrote, u can ask me too ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should read more about `padding` for white spaces around the main box above.
2. Also for the curve box above you should use `position: absolute` for child which here is the curve box and `position: relative` for its parent which it the main box. It helps for positions
3. For rounding the corners you should use `border-radius`.

As you're a new contributer, please read about these on tutorial sites like [w3schools.com](https://w3schools.com). Then if you have any problems send your data and people around here help you.